# Heroku Node JS app error - says it can't find my main module

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a small node.js app running at heroku. Everything was fine until today.

I made a tiny change in one of my .jade files and re-deployed. Now I am getting this in my heroku logs:

```
2013-01-09T20:44:40+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-01-09T20:44:53+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v36 created by steve@donie.us
2013-01-09T20:44:53+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy c299759 by steve@donie.us
`013-01-09T20:44:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node ./doniewebapp.js
2013-01-09T20:44:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2013-01-09T20:44:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2013-01-09T20:44:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
'013-01-09T20:44:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/doniewebapp.js
2013-01-09T20:44:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
2013-01-09T20:44:56+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-09T20:44:56+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2013-01-09T20:44:56+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2013-01-09T20:44:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
2013-01-09T20:44:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-01-09T20:44:54+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-01-09T20:44:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-01-09T20:44:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I have confirmed that the doniewebapp.js file is still there, and I can even run the app if I use

```
heroku run node doniewebapp.js
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same trouble.

> Starting process with command `node ./doniewebapp.js  <-- Backquote  does not exist.

```
$ vi Procfile
:set fileformat=unix
:w
```

I have solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks, good find. Yes, I'm working on a Windows machine. Changing the line endings to unix fixed it. Since I was on a Windows machine, I used my trusty Notepad++ to make the change rather than vi.